# Flutter - Different floating action button in TabBar

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get a different floatting button in a `TabBar` in flutter. But I will try a lot of option, but I don't know how.

Sorry, I add more details:
I want to do a app with a `TabBar`, like this flutter example.
If you see this is a `tabBarDemo` application, I can change between tabs, 
but I don't know how to change the floating button between tabs. Thanks

Like this gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxtN4.gif

```
class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended
            (onPressed: null,
            icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white,),
            label: new Text('FLOATING TO CHANGE'),
            ),
          floatingActionButtonLocation:FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please post code, what you tried. I din't get like "different floating button"

Comment: floating button and tab bar are two different things

Comment: Sorry guys, I have add more information.
I have an example of tabBarDemo, but I need a different floatinActionButton at any tab.
Thanks

Comment: This is covered by the fab-per-tab demo in the flutter gallery: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/tabs_fab_demo.dart

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A Minimal Example of what you want:

```
class TabsDemo extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TabsDemoState createState() => _TabsDemoState();
}

class _TabsDemoState extends State<TabsDemo>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabIndex);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.removeListener(_handleTabIndex);
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleTabIndex() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Demo'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                text: "Tab1",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Tab2",
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ), //   floatingActionButton: _buildFloatingActionButton(context),
        body: TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: [
          Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Text('Tab 1'),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Text('Tab 2'),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
        floatingActionButton: _bottomButtons(),
      ),
    );


}



Widget _bottomButtons() {
    return _tabController.index == 0
        ? FloatingActionButton(
            shape: StadiumBorder(),
            onPressed: null,
            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.message,
              size: 20.0,
            ))
        : FloatingActionButton(
            shape: StadiumBorder(),
            onPressed: null,
            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.edit,
              size: 20.0,
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks this solved my problem!!! :D

A litle question, I don't understand this sintax:

return _tabController.index == 0
        ? FloatingActionButton(

I don't understand the "?", and the ":" (at second part"). Could you explain me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Dart has two operators that let you evaluate expressions that might otherwise require ifelse statements −

condition ? expr1 : expr2
If condition is true, then the expression evaluates expr1 (and returns its value); otherwise, it evaluates and returns the value of expr2.

expr1 ?? expr2
If expr1 is non-null, returns its value; otherwise, evaluates and returns the value of expr2

Comment: I am applying this in making WhatsApp clone to hide my floating button on camera tab open but when I switched to camera tab it takes times to hide the floating actions button and to again mount in the view so it looks weird. Do you have any other solution ?

Comment: If you have a tab, where you don't want to show the FloatingActionButton, just return null.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by `TabController`

**Declaration:** `TabController _tabController;`

**Initialization:** in `initState()`

```
_tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
_tabController.addListener(_handleTabChange);
```

and just pass `setState((){})` in method `_handleTabChange` to reflect ontime like

```
_handleTabChange(){
  setState((){});    
}
```

Now **Bind** or **Inject** in both of widget `TabBar` and `TabBarView` in their controller property.

```
TabBarView(
  controller: _tabController,
  children: [
    Widget(),
    Widget()
  ],
),

TabBar(
  controller: _tabController,
  tabs:[
    Tab(...),
    Tab(...),
  ]
)
```

Now place your different FAB button to different Tabs by according to `_tabController` index

```
floatingActionButton: _tabController.index == 0
 ? FloatingActionButton(
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  onPressed: () {},
 )
 : FloatingActionButton(
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  onPressed: () {},
 ),
```

Keep coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Lista extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ListaState createState() => _ListaState();
}

class _ListaState extends State<Lista> {
  int indexTab=0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      initialIndex: 0,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar (
            title: Text("Test"),
            bottom: TabBar(
              onTap: (index){
                setState(() {
                  indexTab = index;
                });
              },
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: indexTab==0? FloatingActionButton (
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ):FloatingActionButton (
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('test'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('1'),
              Text('2'),
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the accepted answer was not providing a good enough solution for me. The problem is that animation feels laggy and untimely.

The main point of change is listening to Animation of TabController instead of TabController state.

There is my approach to create a more or less reusable solution:

```dart
class MultipleHidableFabs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MultipleHidableFabs> createState() => _MultipleHidableFabsState();
}

class _MultipleHidableFabsState extends State<MultipleHidableFabs>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  // Index of initially opened tab
  static const initialIndex = 0;

  // Number of tabs
  static const tabsCount = 3;

  // List with current scales for each tab's fab
  // Initialize with 1.0 for initial opened tab, 0.0 for others
  final tabScales =
      List.generate(tabsCount, (index) => index == initialIndex ? 1.0 : 0.0);

  late TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(
      length: tabsCount,
      initialIndex: initialIndex,
      vsync: this,
    );

    // Adding listener to animation gives us opportunity to track changes more
    // frequently compared to listener of TabController itself
    tabController.animation!.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        // Current animation value. It ranges from 0 to (tabsCount - 1)
        final animationValue = tabController.animation!.value;
        // Simple rounding gives us understanding of what tab is showing
        final currentTabIndex = animationValue.round();
        // currentOffset equals 0 when tabs are not swiped
        // currentOffset ranges from -0.5 to 0.5
        final currentOffset = currentTabIndex - animationValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < tabsCount; i++) {
          if (i == currentTabIndex) {
            // For current tab bringing currentOffset to range from 0.0 to 1.0
            tabScales[i] = (0.5 - currentOffset.abs()) / 0.5;
          } else {
            // For other tabs setting scale to 0.0
            tabScales[i] = 0.0;
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: tabController,
          tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.one_k)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.two_k)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.three_k)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: tabController,
          children: [Icon(Icons.one_k), Icon(Icons.two_k), Icon(Icons.three_k)],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: createScaledFab(),
    );
  }

  Widget? createScaledFab() {
    // Searching for index of a tab with not 0.0 scale
    final indexOfCurrentFab = tabScales.indexWhere((fabScale) => fabScale != 0);
    // If there are no fabs with non-zero opacity return nothing
    if (indexOfCurrentFab == -1) {
      return null;
    }
    // Creating fab for current index
    final fab = createFab(indexOfCurrentFab);
    // If no fab created return nothing
    if (fab == null) {
      return null;
    }
    final currentFabScale = tabScales[indexOfCurrentFab];
    // Scale created fab with
    // You can use different Widgets to create different effects of switching
    // fabs. E.g. you can use Opacity widget or Transform.translate to create
    // custom animation effects
    return Transform.scale(scale: currentFabScale, child: fab);
  }

  // Create fab for provided index
  // You can skip creating fab for any indexes you want
  Widget? createFab(final int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => print("On first fab clicked"),
        child: Icon(Icons.one_k),
      );
    }
    // Not created fab for 1 index deliberately
    if (index == 2) {
      return FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => print("On third fab clicked"),
        child: Icon(Icons.three_k),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Advantages of this approach:

- Synchronized animation between swiping and showing fabs
- Tapping on tabs also animates in a right manner
- Ability to easily skip creating fabs for selected indexes

See an example in action:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71123870/4087068) from [Ilia Kurtov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4312184/ilia-kurtov), here's a reusable component for tab-dependent FABs.

### Implementation

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef FabBuilder = Widget? Function(int tabIndex);
typedef TransformBuilder = Widget Function(
    BuildContext context, Widget child, double t);
```

The basic idea is to transform the animation from the tab controller to an index and distance (`TabFocus` class) using a custom subclass of [`Animatable`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Animatable-class.html).

```dart
/// Represent a tab index with a distance metric.
class TabFocus {
  /// Distance to the tab
  ///
  /// from 0.0 (on tab) to 1.0 (half way to next or previous tab)
  final double distance;

  /// Index of the tab that closest to the current `t`.
  final int index;

  const TabFocus._({required this.distance, required this.index});

  /// Get the tab focus at a tab position
  factory TabFocus.at(double t) {
    final index = t.round();
    final t0 = index.toDouble();
    final distance = (t - t0).abs() * 2;
    return TabFocus._(distance: distance, index: index);
  }
}

/// Subclass of [Animatable] that transforms a `double t` tab position into a [TabFocus].
class TabFocusAnimatable extends Animatable<TabFocus> {
  @override
  TabFocus transform(double t) => TabFocus.at(t);
  const TabFocusAnimatable();
}
```

When we create our widget, we turn this `Animatable<TabFocus>` into an `Animation<TabFocus>` by attaching it to the [`TabController.animation`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController/animation.html)

```dart
/// A tab-dependent FAB based on <https://stackoverflow.com/a/71123870/4087068>
class TabbedFab extends StatefulWidget {
  TabbedFab(
      {Key? key,
      required TabController tabController,
      FabBuilder? builder,
      Animatable<TabFocus> focusAnimatable = const TabFocusAnimatable(),
      TransformBuilder? transformBuilder})
      : this._(
            key: key,
            builder: builder,
            tabController: tabController,
            fabAnimation: focusAnimatable.animate(tabController.animation!));

  const TabbedFab._(
      {Key? key,
      required this.tabController,
      required this.fabAnimation,
      this.transform = _defaultTransform,
      this.builder})
      : super(key: key);

  final TransformBuilder transform;
  final Animation<TabFocus> fabAnimation;
  final TabController tabController;
  final FabBuilder? builder;

  @override
  State<TabbedFab> createState() => _TabbedFabState();
}
```

We also define a default transformation, that just scales a widget (the FAB) based on a `t` from 0.0 to 1.0.

```dart
/// By default, scale the current floating action button, so that it is full
/// size when the tab is selected
Widget _defaultTransform(BuildContext context, Widget child, double t) {
  return Transform.scale(scale: t, child: child);
}
```

In the widget state class, we listen to the `fabAnimation` and call `setState` only when the index changes.

```dart
class _TabbedFabState extends State<TabbedFab> {
  int currentTab = 0;

  _onTabAnimation() {
    final animationIndex = widget.fabAnimation.value.index;
    if (animationIndex != currentTab) {
      setState(() {
        currentTab = animationIndex;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.fabAnimation.removeListener(_onTabAnimation);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    currentTab = widget.tabController.index;
    widget.fabAnimation.addListener(_onTabAnimation);
    super.initState();
  }

  /* build method, see below */
}
```

Finally, we use an [`AnimatedBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html) with our `transform` to scale the widget while the animation is running.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // Creating fab for current index
  final fab = widget.builder?.call(currentTab);
  // If no fab created return nothing
  if (fab == null) {
    return const SizedBox.shrink();
  }
  return AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: widget.fabAnimation,
    builder: (context, child) {
      // fall back to 0.0 if the animation rolled over, but we're still calling the old builder
      final t = (currentTab == widget.fabAnimation.value.index)
          ? 1.0 - widget.fabAnimation.value.distance
          : 0.0;
      return widget.transform(context, child!, t);
    },
    child: fab,
  );
}
```

### Usage

To use it, add it to your `Scaffold` like so:

```dart
Widget? _createFab(index) {
  return (index == 0)
      ? FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => print("Click!"),
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        )
      : null;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: const <Tab>[
                Tab(text: "Tab 1"),
                Tab(text: "Tab 2")
            ],
        )),
    body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: const <Widget>[
            Center(child: Text("Tab 1")),
            Center(child: Text("Tab 2")),
        ]),
    floatingActionButton:
        TabbedFab(tabController: _tabController, builder: _createFab));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code :

```
floatingActionButton: new Container(
      height: 140.0,
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 60.0,
                  child: new FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                    tooltip: 'Increment',
                    child: new Icon(Icons.add),
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  height: 20.0,
                ), // a space
                Container(
                  height: 60.0,
                  child: new FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: _decremenrCounter,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    tooltip: 'Increment',
                    child: new Icon(Icons.remove),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

screenshot : [image]

here is all the code if you want it : main.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {

      _counter++;
    });
  }

  void _decremenrCounter() {
    setState(() {

      _counter--;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(

          title: new Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: new Center(

          child: new Column(

            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              new Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new Container(
          height: 140.0,
          child: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: new Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 60.0,
                      child: new FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                        tooltip: 'Increment',
                        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ), // a space
                    Container(
                      height: 60.0,
                      child: new FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: _decremenrCounter,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        tooltip: 'Increment',
                        child: new Icon(Icons.remove),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ) // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't need this. I have add more information int the question. Thanks