# How to change floating action button between tabs in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement different floating action button for different tabs in flutter. Upon entering a tab, the previous floating action button should hide and a new floating action button should appear (with animation). I have already implemented the method described in [Flutter - Different floating action button in TabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399223/flutter-different-floating-action-button-in-tabbar)
which works fine, but does not animate, and also delays in changing. So is there any better way to implement this desired behavior as shown below ?

[image: Floating action button]

Comment: You can set it by index

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `tabController` to get the index of the current tab. Then call `setState` to change the UI, eg `setState(() => _myIndex = tabController.index )`

Based on `_myIndex` display the button you want for the current tab.